# How do I stop Mendeley referencing in text citations with two names before et al. ? It ONLY does this for references with 3 authors

Tags: reference, citations, mendeley

My in text citations must be harvard referencing but with et al. if there are more that 2 authors. Listing only 1 name followed by et al. : (Smith et al., 2009)
However, Mendeley is writing the names of two authors before et al. but only when there are 3 authors in total. How do i stop this?
These are my inline citation et al. settings:

et-al-min   3,
et-al-use-first    1,
et-al-subsequent-min    (left blank),
et-al-subsequent-use-first (left blank)

In text these are the citations I get:
1 author (Smith, 2009),
2 authors (Smith and Jones, 2008),
3 authors (Smith, Jones, et al., 2007) <<<< how do I stop this??,
4 authors or more (Smith et al., 2004)

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the first author followed by et al when there are two or more authors you should set `et-al-min 2, et-al-use-first 1, et-al-subsequent-min (blank), et-al-subsequent-use-first (blank)`

As per [CSL specification](http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/stable/specification.html#et-al) use of `et-al-min` / `et-al-use-first` attributes enable et-al abbreviation. If the number of names in a name variable matches or exceeds the number set on et-al-min, the rendered name list is truncated after reaching the number of names set on et-al-use-first.

So that would mean it first uses one name (`et-al-use-first 1`) when there are a minimum of two authors (`et-al-min 2`) before showing et al.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (seemingly), but it turned out that it was caused not directly because of CSL regarding et-al settings:
It results from two papers of the same author and year in my bibliography.
If I delete one of the paper citations, then this issue does not appear any more.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29963575)

Comment: @Kartikey You are right, but I am not asking a question here. Instead I want to lead others who have the same "symptom" of (Smith, Jones, et al., 2007), although they have their CSL settings like Nathan proposes, to a possible other reason for it.